# How to loop over a list in spring xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-el

We have a requirement where we have a list created in a property file.

Now we want to loop over this list and populate a util map in spring bean. The key of the map shall be the list elements while value is a constant bean.

for example

in our properites file:

List=element1,element2,element3 and so on

now in our bean something like

```
for (listelement:List)
<utilmap>
  <entry key=listelement value=anyvalue/>
</utilmap>
```